# Managing django admin filters according to permissions

Tags: python, django, filter, permissions

I am creating a `python django` project and while in admin I want to make it function like this:

the user opens the`customer` window which would show a list of all `customers` then if the user has a certain `permission` a location filter is visible but if there is no `permission` then the filter is not visible.

Is this possible and if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [get_list_filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_filter) method of your `ModelAdmin` and check for permissions in there.

Example:

```
MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_filter(self, request):
        if request.user.has_perm('some_perm'):
            return ['filter_1', 'filter_2', ......]
        else:
            return []
```